# Is burnt THC still psychoactive?

Tags: metabolism, pharmacology

Asking from a more practical angle. If one smokes a joint - does the THC in the embers contribute to getting high - or is it only the THC released by the heat of the smoke in the not-burning section which contributes?

(same question for CBDs - I assume the answer will be equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

The THC molecule needs to be intact to be functional in the brain, so the vaporized THC from your 'joint' will contribute to being high. If the THC molecule burns (disintegrates, I don't know at which temperature this happens), you'll get probably some extra tar which does not contribute.

So all THC molecules that are vaporized by the heat of the burning tip, in or next to the ember, will be functional.

Comment: who voted down and *why*? can you maybe provide a source/study?

Comment: Don't mind the down voters, there are always some frustrated people around. I don't think there is scientific literature about how THC vaporizes from a cigarette. Most THC studies were done by injecting mice and rats (with too high doses). How THC is released from a burning cigarette is also not really a biological question, but is physics.

Comment: at the end of the day the question boils down to whether the heat of the embers destroys or significantly changes the THC molecule - that should be answerable.

Comment: Vaporizing THC under lower (not burning) temperatures give the same psychoactive effect. Vaporizers (sort of electric cigarettes) are very popular today, which do not burn but evaporate the THC from herb. I think you are better of talking to someone in a 'smartshop' instead of finding a scientific publication about this subject.

Comment: yes - of course - I know that - my question refers specifically to the THC burning in the ember. not about whether vaping works.

Comment: But don't you think THC is already vaporized before it can really burn? I mean in a forest fire for example, when a tree burns, the water will vaporize before it disintegrates into H2 and O2.

Comment: that's basically what I would like to figure out. first I would like to know whether THC can be active if burnt - then the conclusion would logically follow and a joint is just a convection vaporizer using smoke.